# Draw emoji to image in Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a custom glyph rendering system in my UI. I need to be able to pull a single emoji from the Operating System's set and render it to an image in memory (i.e., 128x128 RGBA) for export to this glyph rendering system. I've been able to find examples of this on iOS (and it works great when hooked up!), but how would this be done in Android Java? If there's a C/C++ JNI implementation that'd be even better, but I imagine there isn't an API for this in the JNI Android libraries.

I imagine I would need to DrawStringToRect() of some kind?

And yes, I know it's horribly inefficient to use a single image per emoji. Emoji use is infrequent and not a hot path for this.

Comment: In terms of "pull a single emoji from the OS set", what exactly is "the OS set"? In terms of "render it to an image", what exactly are you looking for in terms of output? (PNG? `Bitmap`? something else?)

Comment: 32-bit RGBA raw data, to be precise. But I imagine that I can find other information to convert to what I need once I get it rendered to an image of SOME kind.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `Bitmap` (for 32-bit use `ARGB_8888` Config)
2. Wrap it in `Canvas`
3. Create `Paint` with the desired `Typeface` and `textSize`
4. draw text on `Canvas` (`drawText()` function's y-coordinate is glyph baseline)
5. read `Bitmap` contents (`getPixels()` or `copyPixelsToBuffer()`)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the start hints. Is there any particular technique for sizing the emoji glyph to the image rectangle, or do I need to start with an impossibly large value and loop downward, measuring the size of the glyph until it falls in range?

Comment: Android [autosized text](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview) tries different text sizes with some `granularity`, seems like you will need to implement something similar. See also: [getTextBounds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)), [binary search](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/4955).